# How to use StreamReader and StreamWriter to track button events between users on multiple browsers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, stream

#### Hello, is it possible to use StreamWriter and StreamReader to save and extract from a Server.MapPath(text file) while to keeping track of the interactions between the users(2)?

Each user is able to open up a browser or tabs, connect to the URL, and enter a joining a cue for a tic tac toe game. When the game is started, how can the server track which buttons has been pressed so that the opponent can see where his challenger has played.

Would StreamWriter and StreamReader be initializing a virtual game in the back ground, and then sends HttpRequests by pressing one of the 9 buttons to change the text to X or O. So say I press button 1, 2, and 3, the game has a CheckWinner where it checks if you have won horizontally, vertically, or diagonally. So how can I send (or save to streamwriter) this click event to allow the game to register the button as been clicked?

I'm using Visual Studio '08, ASP.NET website and forms. My players are a class and my game is able to instantiate a separate instance for each game being played

Does anyone know how to do polling? I got this refresh cue, can it be used to track moves of the two players? But I thought for that to work, I need to have my filepath ready and be writing in the moves that the player chooses, right?

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "10");
```

Comment: I suggest you look into HTML5 and what it has available for client/server. As an example, check out the source for BrowserQuest at: https://github.com/mozilla/BrowserQuest

Comment: I haven't done games personally (so bravo to you), but it sounds like a perfect candidate for client side (Javascript/Ajax/xmlhttprequest) - re: user interactions sent to server in background (not interrupting) along with some "polling" to refresh display (so updates are "shared").

Comment: Part of my assignment requires the use of Streams I/O. Should be able to do the same thing as xmlHttpRequest, but I cannot find any reference source to base these HttpRequest calls. Can you show me how to do polling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it uses Streams, but this sounds like a [perfect use for SignalR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx). You could use it to create multiple games between any number of users, and track the status in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

You need [websocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

A modern solution for online full-duplex stream-able  connection, and uses for gaming, chat, event broadcasting, that supports by all major browsers.